# Selenium + Firefox на сервере Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, сервер, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь запустить селениум на сервере, написал тест запуска и при создании экземпляра драйвера всегда получаю ошибку.

**сам код теста**

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service


with Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600)):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(executable_path='./web/geckodriver/geckodriver'))

    driver.get("https://www.python.org")
    print(driver.title)
    driver.close()
```

**ошибка**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/bot_fl/selenium_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(executable_path='./web/geckodriver/geckodriver'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Failed to read marionette port
```

PS: Драйвер пробовал и загруженный из папки и устанавливаемый через webdriver_manager, перепробовал разные версии мозилы которые доступны через snap
PS2: Пробовал указывать Options() с --headless и --no-sandbox - результат тот-же

- Mozilla Firefox 122.0.1
- Python 3.11.7
- geckodriver 0.34.0
- PyVirtualDisplay 3.0
- selenium 4.17.2
- webdriver-manager 4.0.1